# Why doesn't breadcrumb work for taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, breadcrumbs

I have created url patterns for the taxonomy terms in the "Article category" vacabulary.

I want the breadcrumb trail to look like this:

"Accueil"> "Blog"> "Categorie"

But I did not succeed.

Currently the taxonomy terms page only displays "Accueil" in the breadcrumb trail.

Why does this not work with the terms of taxonomy ?

However, I created a Views page for "Blog" and "Categorie".

Here are the parameters of the URL alias patterns :

[image]

Here is the default Views for taxonomy terms in Drupal :

[image]

The term page only displays "Accueil" in the breadcrumbs. It should display "Accueil"> "Blog" > "Catégorie" :

[image]

Comment: My reading of French isn't very good, but is it possible that the contextual filter you're using is the one that expects a numeric ID?

Comment: @LesLim I just updated my question

Comment: Breadcrumbs have nothing to do with URL patterns, they are more like a menu navigation in Drupal core. You might want to try EasyBreadcrumb module to go into this direction.

Comment: @Hudri Thanks, this module is great and it fixes my problem.